# recursive solution to find index of match for two strings

Tags: recursion

My code below will return random values for the matching starting index for two strings. 
For example, if s = Mississippi, and t = sip, the function should return 6. I set my code up, so that it would print out the value of m just before it returns it. Indeed, my program prints out 6, but then it returns random values in the millions.

```
int index_of_sub(string s, string t, int m)
{
  if(s.length() - m < t.length())
  {
    return -1; 
  }
  if(s.substr(m, t.length()) == t)
  {
    cout << m << endl; 
    return m; 
  }
  else
  {
    index_of_sub(s, t, m + 1); 
  }
}//end index_of_sub function
int index_of(string s, string t)
{
  return index_of_sub(s, t, 0); 
}//end index_of function
```

Comment: First thing is, Do you know if the `==` comparison works for strings?

Comment: @user7348 You can accept me answer by clicking the green check mark. Please do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `return` statement on your last `else`.

```
else
{
   return index_of_sub(s, t, m + 1); 
   ^^^^^^
}
```

Since you are not explicitly returning the result of this recursive call, a garbage value is being returned which is why you are getting such strange results.

Comment: Good job jlars62. How embarrassing for me! Sorry, I can't upvote you. I just joined. And, as you can tell, I just started programming.